# XUL Tree. How to query nsITreeView

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

How to use nsI* interfaces in JS of FireFox Addon? 
I know about that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/tree
and I want use nsITreeView: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsITreeView

I don't find any info about calling this interface via JS for selected tree:

```
var t = document.getElementById('MySuperTree'); //How to get interface for THIS tree?
```

Can anybody give me simple example?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Question solved. Just use:

```
mySuperTree.view.<nsIViewTree Interface usage>
```